После деактивации плагина Polylang перестал отображаться сайт. Белый экран
Есть сайт по адресу
test.baltimir.ee
Когда деактивируешь плагин Polylang получается вот так

Сайт на WordPress и делался изначально для трех языков.
Нужно чтобы сайт все равно работал после деактивации плагина Polylang. Как решить эту проблему

При использовании функций Polylang, проверять активен ли плагин, либо существует ли та функция которую Вы используете, можно еще создать фолбеки для этих функций

см ошибки

У вас ssl перестал работать...
Проверьте файл .htaccess
Иногда проблемы с SSL могут быть связаны с настройками в файле .htaccess. Проверьте, есть ли там правила для перенаправления на HTTPS. Если есть, убедитесь, что они правильно настроены.
Проверьте настройки сайта
Убедитесь, что в настройках WordPress (Настройки -> Общие) указаны правильные URL-адреса для вашего сайта (с HTTPS).
Проверьте логи сервера
Проверьте логи сервера на наличие ошибок. Это могут быть логи Apache, Nginx или другие, в зависимости от вашего хостинга.
Обратитесь к хостинг-провайдеру
Если вы не можете самостоятельно решить проблему, обратитесь к вашему хостинг-провайдеру. Часто поддержка помогает вам диагностировать и устранить проблему.
